# Get array values in pairs javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

so I have an array in which I store values in pairs. I can't use an object because keys may repeat so I use an array instead.

This is how the array may look:

```
array = ['id1', 'id5', 'id9', 'id12', 'id2', 'id9', 'id1', 'id4'];
```

So I want to iterate through it and get all the pairs, so I can use them for another function:

```
var a = 'id1';
var b = 'id5';    
doStuffWithThePair(a, b);

var a = 'id9';
var b = 'id12';    
doStuffWithThePair(a, b);

var a = 'id2';
var b = 'id9';    
doStuffWithThePair(a, b);

var a = 'id1';
var b = 'id4';    
doStuffWithThePair(a, b);
```

I tried with for loops, using `if(i%2 == 0)` but it doesn't work. How can I make this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about that: `for (var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i=i+2) { doStuffWithThePair(array[i], array[i+1]) }` ?

Comment: Realized that right after I submitted the question, if you want feel free answer it to I can mark it as correct for other to see it in the future!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate through your array like this:

```js
function doStuffWithThePair(a, b) {
    // your code is here.
    console.log(a, b);
}

var array = ['id1', 'id5', 'id9', 'id12', 'id2', 'id9', 'id1', 'id4'];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i += 2) { 
    doStuffWithThePair(array[i], array[i + 1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function doStuffWithThePair (x, y) {
  console.log("x: " + x + ", y: " + y);
}

var a = ['id1', 'id5', 'id9', 'id12', 'id2', 'id9', 'id1', 'id4'];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i+=2) { 
  doStuffWithThePair(a[i], a[i+1]);
}
```